# When telephonemanager.getSimState() returns SIM_STATE_READY

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager

Can anybody explain when exactly the method `telephonemanager.getSimState()` returns a `SIM_STATE_READY` in Dual sim phone? In other words, when sim is present/active and connected to network, or when sim is present/active and it may or may not be connected to network?

Answer (score 0):

SIM_STATE_READY will be returned when the sim is present, has been validated by pin code and a connection to the network has been made.

You can deduce this from putting the phone into airplane mode. Your sim will have a status of UNKNOWN.

Comment: thanku so much , but in Karbon A21+ Dual Sim Phone,  master slot is CDMA(Without Sim) and Slave slot is GSM (With Sim) though slave sim is active, it is returning as UNKNOWN.

Comment: Another one doubt is if sim is not in ready state we cannot get cell location Id and cellId ... right?

Comment: What about my first question regarding karbon A21+.